# Edit Eval()'d JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Take the following object. I'm trying to pass a string path to "gold", eval() it and then increment it like so:

```
var inv = {
    "gold" : 10
}

eval('inv.gold')++;
```

It's not working however. I've tried using JSON.parse as well but it didn't work (whether it was me writing it wrong or something else I don't know).

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/5JQNm/ ?

Comment: why are you eval'ing this instead of using `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans why would he need to JSON.parse a JavaScript object?

Comment: This object was just an example. The object I actually want to alter is extremely large and I am trying to make a function that can edit it more deeply, so I want to pass a string through instead of calling the property directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eval() will evaluate or execute an argument, so you'll need the `++` inside of that:

```
eval('inv.gold++');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JQNm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to eval here, but simply use an iterator function. For instance:

```
function setProperty(object, chain, value) {
  if(typeof chain === "string") {
    chain = chain.split(".");
  }
  if(chain.length === 1) {
    object[chain[0]] = value;
  } else {
    setProperty(object, chain.slice(1), value);
  }
}
```

But the real question is of course why you need to set the value based on a full accessor chain, because that's usually an indication something's not quite right (outside of writing a parser or the like)